# After declaring computed variable, compiler started complaining class has no initializer

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have created a class inherits `UITableViewCell`:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
  override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

There is no compiler error. Then, I declared a computed variable:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
   var student: Student{
       willSet {...}
   }
   ...
}
```

Now, compiler start complaining `Class 'MyCell' has no initializers`. Then, I defined an empty initialier:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
       init(){}

       var student: Student{
           willSet {...}
       }
       ...
    }
```

The error still exist. Why after declared computed variable, compiler starts complaining that error & how to get rid of that error?

Comment: You cant initialize a cell with `init`. Did you try `override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {}`. Don't forget to call `super` though.

Comment: xcode tells me I have to implement `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`, how to implement that in `MyCell` class ?

Comment: Same as before. `required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {}`

Comment: If I only call super in those initializers, I got new error : variable `student` not initialized at super init call.

Comment: The variable isn't a computed property, by the way, it's a stored property with a property observer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try these:

**Option 1:**

```
var student: Student! {
      willSet {...}
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
var student: Student? {
      willSet {...}
}
```

because we must init a variable otherwise compiler will give error. Here in **option 1** we have declared this variable as **implicitly unwrapped optional**. It means it's initial value is nil but it's value will not be nil in future. In **option 2** we have declared this variable as **optional** it means initially its nil and in future it might not have a value. Or you can init a variable here as below.

**Option 3:**

```
var student: Student = Student() {
      willSet {...}
}
```

But here you are using `willSet{}` it means you are getting dynamically value than rather than compile time. So I think first option will remove your error. You should try the best option that suits you best.

**Conclusion**
**We must init a variable.**

Comment: what is the proper way to check student is nil or not in `willSet` block if I make it optional? is it `willSet{if let stu = newValue{...}}`? Could you please include this part in your answer as well?

Comment: yes you can check the new value like this for non nil value.

Answer (score 1):

The recommended solution in a table view cell where the (non-optional) data model item is set in `cellForRow...` is an implicit unwrapped optional.

There is no need to override any initializer.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    var student: Student! {
        willSet {...}
    }

}
```

Note:

`student` is **not** a computed property. Property observers can only be used in stored properties.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your student an optional var

```
var student: Student? {
       willSet {...}
}
```

Comment: You can't abuse optionals if the property isn't optional.

Comment: @Desdenova In this case the property cannot be non-optional. If the cell is reused and designed in Interface Builder `init(coder` is called. However the proper solution is an implicit unwrapped optional.

Comment: @vadian Yes seems like it.

Comment: @Roee84, what is the proper way to check student is nil or not in `willSet` block if I make it optional? is it `willSet{if let stu = newValue{...}}`?

Comment: @Leem.fin Usually in a table view cell the model item (student) is set in `cellForRow...` so it's guaranteed that the value is not `nil`. Declare the property as implicit unwrapped optional (`Student!`)

Comment: What @vadian said